# Pygame events class

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a simplified Events class for pygame, i have been looking at [this](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Efreevial/freevial/trunk/view/head:/src/common/events.py) example, and looks like what i have been looking for, but when I run it i get an error:

```
if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'type'
```

I have made small edits to the code, here is my code in full:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#
# Freevial
# Common event-related classes and functions
#
# Copyright (C) 2007-2009 The Freevial Team
#
# By Carles Oriol i Margarit <carles@kumbaworld.com>
# By Siegfried-Angel Gevatter Pujals <siggi.gevatter@gmail.com>
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#

import sys
import re
import pygame

##from freevialglob import screenshot, if2


mouseButtons = {
        'primary': 1,
        'secondary': 2,
        'middle': 3,
    }

# Aliases for PS2 remotes
joystick_aliases = {
        0: pygame.K_RETURN,
        1: pygame.K_ESCAPE,
        2: pygame.K_RETURN,
        3: pygame.K_s,
        4: pygame.K_F2,
        5: pygame.K_a,
        6: pygame.K_F1,
        7: pygame.K_F3,
        8: pygame.K_SPACE,
        9: pygame.K_ESCAPE,
        12: pygame.K_UP,
        13: pygame.K_RIGHT,
        14: pygame.K_DOWN,
        15: pygame.K_LEFT,
    }

class EventHandle:
    """
    
    This class takes a pygame event and creates an object with convenient
    methods to identify it.
    
    """
    
    global mouseButtons
    
    def __init__(self, event, do_base_actions = True):
        
        if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            event = self._convert_joystick_event(event)
        
        self.event = event
        # The following line should be deprecated when eventLoop improves.
        self.type = event.type
        self.handled = False
        
        if do_base_actions and self.base_actions():
            self.handled = True
    
    
    def _convert_joystick_event(self, event):
        
        if joystick_aliases.get(event.button):
            return pygame.event.Event(pygame.KEYUP, { 'key': joystick_aliases[ event.button ], 'unicode': u's', 'mod': 0 })
    
    
    def _getKey(self, key):
        
        if type(key) is str:
            
            if key[:2] != 'K_':
                key = 'K_' + key
            
            key = getattr(pygame, key)
        
        return key
    
    
    def _isKeyEvent(self):
        
        return hasattr(self.event, 'key') 
    
    
    def _isStateEvent(self):
        
        return hasattr(self.event, 'state') 
    
    
    def _hasKey(self, keynames):
        
        if not self._isKeyEvent():
            return False
        
        if len(keynames) == 1 and type(keynames[0]) is tuple:
            keynames = keynames[0]
        
        for key in keynames:
            
            if self.event.key == self._getKey(key):
                return True
        
        return False
    
    
    def isKey(self, *keynames):
        
        return self._hasKey(keynames)
    
    
    def isUp(self):
        
        return self.event.type == pygame.KEYUP 
    
    
    def isDown(self):

        return self.event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN
    
    
    def isClick(self, request = 0):
        
        if type(request) is not int:
            request = mouseButtons[ request ]
        
        return self.event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and (self.event.button == request or request == 0) 
    
    
    def isRelease(self, request = 0):
        
        if type(request) is not int:
            request = mouseButtons[ request ]
        
        return self.event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and (self.event.button == request or request == 0) 
        
    
    def keyUp(self, *keynames):
        
        if not self.isUp():
            return False
        
        if len(keynames) == 0:
            return True
        
        return self.isKey(*keynames)
    
    
    def keyDown(self, *keynames):
        
        if not self.isDown():
            return False
        
        if len(keynames) == 0:
            return True
        
        return self.isKey(keynames)
    
    
    def isWindowMinimize(self):
        
        return self._isStateEvent() and self.event.state == 6 and self.event.gain == 0
    
    def isWindowRestore(self):
        
        return self._isStateEvent() and self.event.state == 4 and self.event.gain == 1
    
    def isWindowFocusLose(self):
        
        return self._isStateEvent() and self.event.state == 1 and self.event.gain == 0
    
    def isWindowFocusGain(self):
        
        return self._isStateEvent() and self.event.state == 1 and self.event.gain == 1
    
    def isQuit(self):
        
        return  self.event.type == pygame.QUIT
    
    def str(self):
        
        return if2(self._isKeyEvent(), printKey(self.event.key), '')
    
    def is_user_action(self):
        
        return self.event.type in (pygame.KEYUP, pygame.KEYDOWN,
            pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP, pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN)
    
    def base_actions(self):
        
        if self.isQuit():
            sys.exit()
        
        elif self.keyDown('PRINT'):
            screenshot(pygame.display.get_surface())
            return True
        
        elif self.isWindowFocusLose() or self.isWindowFocusGain():
            # Those aren't interesting, skip them.
            # We could also do some CPU saving here, but this would produce
            # bad synchronization between the music and the images.
            return True
        
        elif self.keyUp('F11'):
            pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()
            return True
        
        elif self.isWindowMinimize():
            pauseGameUntilRestore()
            return True
        
        else:
            return False


def eventLoop():
    """
    
    Generator which runs through the event loop, takes care of global
    events and yields the unhandled event objects.
    
    This function may be expanded in the future to add support for
    external events (which could come from DBUS or other sources).
    
    """
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        eventhandle = EventHandle(event)
        if eventhandle.handled: continue
        yield eventhandle

def waitForMouseRelease():

    while pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] + pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[1] + pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2] != 0:
        pygame.event.wait() 


def pauseGameUntilRestore():
    
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if EventHandle(event).isWindowRestore():
                return False
        
        # Sleep for 10 milliseconds.
        # This has no visible effect but will drastically reduce CPU usage.
        pygame.time.wait(10)


aobert = atancat = adieresi = acirc = False
accents = [u"aeiou", u"àèìòù", u"áéíóú", u"äëïöü", u"âêîôû" ]

def printKey(tecla):
    """ Translates a pygame Key object for on-game printing of it's value. """

    global aobert, atancat, adieresi, acirc, accents
    
    keyname = pygame.key.name(tecla)
    
    if keyname == 'space': 
        return ' '
    
    if keyname == 'world 71':
        if pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_SHIFT:
            return u'Ç'
        else:
            return u'ç'
    
    if keyname == 'tab':
        return '    '
    
    if len(keyname) == 3 and keyname[:1] == '[' and keyname[2:] == ']':
        keyname = keyname[1:2]
    
    pos = accents[0].find(keyname)
    if pos != -1:
        if aobert: keyname = accents[1][pos]
        if atancat: keyname = accents[2][pos]
        if adieresi: keyname = accents[3][pos]
        if acirc: keyname = accents[4][pos]
    
    if pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_SHIFT:
        keyname = keyname.upper()
    
    if tecla == 314:
        if pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_SHIFT:
            atancat = True
        elif pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL:
            adieresi = True
        elif pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_ALT:
            acirc = True
        else:
            aobert = True
    else:
        aobert = atancat = adieresi = acirc = False
    
    if not re.search(u"^[a-zA-Z0-9,.+'-/*àèìòùáéíóúäëïöüâêîôû ]$", keyname):
        return ''
    
    return keyname

event = pygame.event.get()
events = EventHandle(event)
```

I dont need joystick events, just key and mouse. I just want a simple abrstaction and this seems to do this, but it doesnt look like it works,

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is right at the very end of your code:

```
event = pygame.event.get() 
events = EventHandle(event)
```

[`event.get()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) gives you a *list of events*, which is why you usually see, as you have correctly used elsewhere in your code:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
```

Your `EventHandle.__init__` is expecting only a single event, not a list of them. For a single event, you can use [`event.poll()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.poll):

```
event = EventHandle(pygame.event.poll())
```